# Updating data range in a chart in PowerPoint - Nothing seems to happen

Tags: vba, charts, range, powerpoint

The data range does not change when I run this code. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object

Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open ("C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Standard template.potx")

myPresentation.Slides(4).Select 'Slide 4 contains my graph
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes(3).Select 'Shape 3 is my graph

Call ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes(3).Chart.SetSourceData(Source:="'[C:\Users\Mike\Documents\My source file.xlsm]Graph data'!$B$21:$H$22", PlotBy:=xlRows)

Call ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes(3).Chart.Refresh
```

Comment: Side note: drop the `Call`s.

Comment: I can remove the Call on the refresh but not on the SetSourceData line. It tells me "= expected" if I do. I also tried replacing the Call with a variable = to the line, but it is still pointing the data to the old source.

Comment: You need to drop the parentheses around the parameters too